# How to do file access on non http htmls?

Tags: html

I tried to use the filesystem api from a html file which is opened locally, not via web.
Therefore there is NO associated domain.

Is there an api which allows to work with local files when started an html locally (e.g. file:///abc.html).

I tried

```
window.requestFileSystem
```

and the webkit variant. However, this does only work when calling from  **http://abc.html** but not when calling **file://abc.html**:

I use chrome 26... on windows

Comment: what about relative reference, ie, ../../abc.html or ./path/to/abc.html